# Access desktop files from Linux terminal in college server

Tags: linux, desktop

[image]

I am trying to access my desktop files from the college server. I can access my desktop files: `cd /mnt/c/Users/Username/Desktop` from the Linux terminal, but once I get to my college server using ssh, I cannot access the desktop files using the same command. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: add the message that you get when typing that command. Most likely the path is different inside the server. On linux systems desktop can be accessesed `cd ~/Desktop`

Comment: Actually I am in Ubuntu. I have added the picture

Comment: Probably the directory is not mounted, gets mounted once you login via GUI only (?). Inspect `/etc/fstab` for that as well as the output of `mount` command.